# VB.NET Bound ComboBox SelectedValue does not display

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I bind a datatable to the combobox.DataSource on load. I then give the combobox a DisplayMember and a ValueMember (2 different columns out of the datatable). In the SelectedIndexChanged of the combobox I would like to use the SelectedValue property of the combobox, just to test I MsgBox(combobox.SelectedValue) and I get "Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'." Why isn't it displaying the value? :(

```
OnLoad
    cbCISoftware.DataSource = dbMaps.Tables("maps")
    cbCISoftware.ValueMember = "id"
    cbCISoftware.DisplayMember = "name"

SelectedIndexChanged of cbCISoftware
    MsgBox(cbCISoftware.SelectedValue)

SelectedValue.ToString outputs
    System.Data.DataRowView
```

Comment: Can you add your databinding code and the selectedindexchanged code so we can double-check?

Comment: Added the code! (also the DisplayMember shows fine on the form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you need to bind the table's DefaultView:

```
cbCISoftware.DataSource = dbMaps.Tables("maps").DefaultView
```

Comment: The only thing is, OnLoad when it assigns the datasource I have to create an exception for the combobox_SelectedIndexChanged because it still outputs System.Data.DataRowView as SelectedValue (and it only fires once) but after datasource assignment it works fine. HOWEVER if you put the exception handling under SelectedValueChanged, this event fires twice and the second time it is with the proper value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to be sure to have selected `DropDownList` as `DropDownStyle` for the `Combobox` and that the binding is working.

Then you have to replace `MsgBox(cbCISoftware.SelectedValue)`
with `MsgBox(cbCISoftware.SelectedValue.ToString)`

Otherwise to obtain the result, `MsgBox(cbCISoftware.Text)` will work, but it not probably what you are looking for :-)

I can provide you with complete code to do the binding if you need it.